# Tensors and multilinear maps isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

> Prove that there is a natural isomorphism between the space $T^{(k+1,l)}(V)$ of $(k+1,l)$-tensors over $V$ and the space of multilinear maps
> $$
> \underbrace{V^\ast \times \dots \times V^\ast}_{k \text{ factors }} \times  \underbrace{V \times \dots \times V}_{l \text{ factors }} \to V.
> $$ Here $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space.

For any multilinear map $f : V^\ast \times \dots \times V^\ast \times V \times \dots \times V \to V$ the universal property of tensor products implies that there exists a linear $\tilde{f}: V^\ast \otimes \dots \otimes V^\ast \otimes V \otimes \dots \otimes V \to V$ that agrees with $f$ in the sense that $\tilde{f}(v^*_1 \otimes \dots \otimes v^*_k \otimes v_1\otimes\dots \otimes v_l) = f(v^*_1,\dots,v_k^*,v_1,\dots,v_l)$. Since $\tilde{f} \in \operatorname{Hom}(V^\ast \otimes \dots \otimes V^\ast \otimes V \otimes \dots \otimes V, V)$ and this space is isomorphic to $k+1$ copies of $V$ tensored with $l$ copies of $V^\ast$ the proof should follow.

Is this are there is to it or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Let $M$ denote the space of multiplinear maps from $(V^*)^k\times V^l$ into $V$. Let $H=\text{Hom}(V^*\otimes\ldots \otimes V^*\otimes V\otimes\ldots \otimes V,V)$. Let $T=T^{(k+1,l)}(V)$. What you've described is a function $J$ from $M$ to $H$. You then (correctly) state that $H$ is isomorphic to $T$., which means there exists an isomorphism $I:H\to T$. The desired isomorphism would then be the composition $IJ:M\to T$. But in order to know that this is an isomorphism, you need to know that your function $Jf=\tilde{f}$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I don't quite follow this. Isn't it the universality here that is giving me a one-to-one correspondence? @user114263

Comment: I've never heard that included as part of the definition of the universal property. Of course, that is a property enjoyed by the universal property, but in a sense that may be among the things you're expected to prove here. Can you state the universal property, exactly as you're using it? Typically it's a "there exists" (as you've worded it here), which would not prove injectivity, surjectivity, or linearity of $J$.

Comment: Yea, you are correct. It’s just universality. I don’t think you need to say anything more.

Comment: Now I'm slightly confused, user114263 seems to think differently? @Deane

Comment: Something doesn't seem right here -- if $k=l=0$ then this is asserting a natural isomorphism between $V^*$ and $V$, which does not exist. Also, if you correct the indices so that this problem goes away, you still need to assume that $V$ is finite-dimensional in order for $\mathrm{Hom}(V,V)$ to be isomorphic to $V^*\otimes V$ (which is the $(0,1)$ case).

Comment: I'm assuming $V$ is finite-dimensional. Forgot to mention. @krm2233

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The universal property of the tensor product can be rephrased to say that there is a canonical identification of
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
\mathrm{Hom}(V_1,\mathrm{Hom}(V_2,W)) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(V_1\otimes V_2,W)
$$
essentially because the left-hand side is just a cumbersome way of say "bilinear maps from $V_1\times V_2$ to $W$".

Indeed a linear map $\phi$ from $V_1$ to $\mathrm{Hom}(V_2,W)$ is a  linear map which takes a vector $v_1$ to a linear map $\phi(v_1)\colon V_2 \to W$. Thus, given vectors $v_1 \in V_1$ and $v_2\in V_2$, $\phi$ provides the vector $\phi(v_1)(v_2) \in W$, and the map $(v_1,v_2) \to \phi(v_1)(v_2)$ is linear in each of $v_1$ and $v_2$ separately, that is, it is a bilinear map. This argument runs in reverse and so establishes that
$$
\mathrm{Hom}(V_1,\mathrm{Hom}(V_2,W)) \cong \mathrm{Bil}(V_1\times V_2, W) = \{f\colon V_1\times V_2 \to W\mid f\text{ linear in each factor}\}.
$$

But now if $V$ is any vector space, $V \cong \mathrm{Hom}(\mathsf k,V)$ and so if $V$ is finite-dimensional so that the canonical map $d\colon V \to V^{**} = \mathrm{Hom}(V^*,\mathsf k)$ is an isomorphism, then we have

$$
\begin{split}
\mathrm{Hom}\left((V^*)^{\otimes k}\otimes V^{\otimes l}, V \right) 
&= \mathrm{Hom}\left((V^*)^{\otimes k}\otimes V^{\otimes l},\mathrm{Hom}(V^*,\mathsf k)\right)\\
&\cong \mathrm{Hom}\left((V^*)^{\otimes k}\otimes V^{\otimes l}\otimes V^*,\mathsf k\right) \\
&\cong \mathrm{Hom}\left((V^*)^{\otimes(k+1)}V^{\otimes l},\mathsf k\right)\\
&\cong \left((V^*)^{\otimes(k+1)}\otimes V^{\otimes l}\right)^*\\
&\cong (V^*)^{\otimes l}\otimes V^{\otimes(k+1)}
\end{split}
$$
where in going from the second-last to the last line we use the fact that $V$ is finite-dimensional: if $V_1,V_2$ are finite-dimensional, then $(V_1\otimes V_2)^*\cong V_1^*\otimes V_2^*$, where, in general, multiplication gives a canonical map $V_1^*\otimes V_2^* \to (V_1\otimes V_2)^*$

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be less confusing to explain it this way:

First, given vector spaces $W_1, \dots, W_m$ and another vector space $V$, the universal property of the tensor product gives a natural isomorphism between the space of multilinear maps of the form
$$ f: W_1\times\cdots\times W_m \rightarrow V $$
and the space of linear maps of the form
$$ \tilde{f}: W_1\otimes \cdots \otimes W_m \rightarrow V. $$

Second, given vector spaces $T, V$, there is a natural isomorphism between the space of linear maps of the form
$$ L: T \rightarrow V $$
and the space $T^*\otimes V$.

Third, There is a natural isomorphism
$$
(W_1\otimes\cdots \otimes W_m)^* \simeq W_1^*\otimes \cdots\otimes W_m^*.
$$

You can prove all of this yourself easily.

The case you're looking at is when $m = k+l$, $W_1=\cdots=W_k= V^*$, $W_{k+1}=\cdots=W_{k+l}=V$, and
$$
T = W_1\otimes\cdots\otimes W_m = V^*\otimes\cdots V^*\otimes V\cdots\otimes V.
$$

Comment: You mean $V\otimes T^*$.

Comment: Oops. Thanks, @blargoner